# how do you create a large-hdpi AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

i've got Eclipse 3.7.2 and Android plugin v23.0.2.1259578

what settings to i have to give in order to create an emulator that will pick up resources from res/layout-large-hdpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nexus 7 should do it if you have that in the list